# How to make sure items are added to the end of a moving list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When the user clicks "Music", "Movie", or "Computer", an item is supposed to be added to the end of that moving list. Instead, the item gets added at the beginning... and if you click the next or previous button and then try adding an item, the item will get added at a seemingly random place.

How can this be fixed...?

http://jsfiddle.net/neowot/dawvjcta/1/

HTML

```
    <div id="choices">
        <ul id="MusicDiv"><li>Music</li></ul>
        <ul id="MovieDiv"><li>Movie</li></ul>
        <ul id="ComputerDiv"><li>Computer</li></ul>
    </div>


    <div id="container">

        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btnPrevious">Previous</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btnNext">Next</a>
        <div class="carousel">
            <ul>
                <li><a>x</a>1</li>
                <li><a>x</a>2</li>
                <li><a>x</a>3</li>
                <li><a>x</a>4</li>
                <li><a>x</a>5</li>
                <li><a>x</a>6</li>
                <li><a>x</a>7</li>
                <li><a>x</a>8</li>
                <li><a>x</a>9</li>
                <li><a>x</a>10</li>
                <li><a>x</a>11</li>
                <li><a>x</a>12</li>
            </ul>
        </div>    

    </div>
```

CSS

```
    #MusicDiv {
        background-color:lightblue;
        width:100px;
        text-align:center;
    }

    #MovieDiv {
        background-color:lightgreen;
        width:100px;
        text-align:center;
    }

    #ComputerDiv {
        background-color:orange;
        width:100px;
        text-align:center;
    }

    #choices li:hover {
        cursor:pointer;
    }



    #container {
        width:auto;
        height:100px;
        background-color:grey;
    }


    .carousel {
        padding-top: 20px;
        width: 357px;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 50px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .carousel ul {
        position: relative;
        list-style: none;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        height: 50px;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .carousel ul li {
        position: absolute;
        height: 25px;
        width: 50px;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 1px;
        background: #f2f2f2;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 25px;
    }
    .carousel a {
        color:red;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        right:5px;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
```

JS

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(document).on('click', '#MusicDiv li', function(event) {
            alert('TestMusic');
            $('<li>Music</li>').appendTo('.carousel ul');
            $(".carousel ul").find('li').last().focus();
        });

        $(document).on('click', '#MovieDiv li', function(event) {
            alert('TestMovie');
            $('<li>Movie</li>').appendTo('.carousel ul');
            $(".carousel ul").find('li').last().focus();
        });

        $(document).on('click', '#ComputerDiv li', function(event) {
            alert('TestComputer');
            $('<li>Comp</li>').appendTo('.carousel ul');
            $(".carousel ul").find('li').last().focus();
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.carousel ul li a', function(event) {
            alert('TestXButton');
            $(this).parent().fadeOut();
        });




        $(function(){
                var carousel = $('.carousel ul');
                var carouselChild = carousel.find('li');
                var clickCount = 0;
                var canClick = true;

                function numberOfElements() {
                    var carWidth=carousel.parent().width();
                    var elemWidth=carouselChild.width();
                    return Math.floor(carWidth/elemWidth);
                }

                var moveWith=numberOfElements();

                itemWidth = carousel.find('li:first').width()+1; //Including margin

                //Set Carousel width so it won't wrap
                carousel.width(itemWidth*carouselChild.length);

                //Place the child elements to their original locations.
                refreshChildPosition();



                //Set the event handlers for buttons.
                $('.btnNext').click(function(){
                    if(canClick){
                        canClick = false;

                        //Animate the slider to left as item width 
                        carousel.stop(false, true).animate({
                            left : '-='+itemWidth*moveWith
                        },600, function(){
                            //Find the first item and append it as the last item.
                            for (var i=0; i<moveWith; i++) {
                                clickCount++;
                                lastItem = carousel.find('li:first');
                                lastItem.remove().appendTo(carousel);
                                lastItem.css('left', (((carouselChild.length-1+clickCount)*(itemWidth))));
                            }
                            //refreshChildPosition();
                            canClick = true;
                        });
                    }
                });

                $('.btnPrevious').click(function(){
                    if(canClick){
                        canClick = false;
                        //Find the first item and append it as the last item.
                        for (var i=0; i<moveWith; i++) {
                        clickCount--;
                        lastItem = carousel.find('li:last');
                        lastItem.remove().prependTo(carousel);
                        console.log(itemWidth*(clickCount));
                        lastItem.css('left', itemWidth*clickCount);
                        }
                        //Animate the slider to right as item width 
                        carousel.finish(true).animate({
                            left: '+='+itemWidth*numberOfElements()
                        },300, function(){
                            canClick = true;
                        });
                    }
                });

                function refreshChildPosition(){
                    carouselChild.each(function(){
                        $(this).css('left', itemWidth*carouselChild.index($(this)));
                    });
                }
            });


    });
```

Comment: items are added to the end...look at the live html in browser dev tools. You are using absolute position but not giving new items any position so they default to `left:0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The items are properly inserted into the DOM. However, you don't set their position. After inserting them you need to call the function `refreshChildPosition()`. And you need to extend it to update the `carouselChild` collection at the beginning:

```
function refreshChildPosition(){
    carouselChild = carousel.find('li'); // this is new

    carouselChild.each(function(){
        $(this).css('left', itemWidth*carouselChild.index($(this)));
    });
}
```

Of course you need to make the function accessible in the outer scope. If you want to make only minor changes, I suggest you add a variable in the outer scope that you assign it to from the scope in which `refreshChildPosition()` is defined:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var refresh;

    // ...
    // the click handlers (now calling refresh() at the end)
    // ...

    $(function(){
        var carousel = $('.carousel ul');
        var carouselChild = carousel.find('li');
        var clickCount = 0;
        var canClick = true;
        refresh = refreshChildPosition; // <-- give it to the outer scope

        // ... rest of your code
```

This is certainly not the nicest solution but at least it solves your immediate problem.

Comment: Thank you. That works well. I am wondering, though, if you know why this only seems to work if the user is on "page 1" of the carousel (i.e., hasn't hit "Next" or "Previous"). The updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/neowot/dawvjcta/1/

Comment: This looks pretty much like the original version.